# How to give one specific user rights to a folder in Inno Setup

Tags: windows, permissions, installation, inno-setup, acl

I want to give folder rights to one specific user (not user groups). I have seen multiple examples but it give rights to whole user group.

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}"; Permissions: users-full
```

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection

I tried this, but I received an error

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}"; Permissions: John-full
```

> Error on line 68 in D:\installer.iss: Parameter "Permissions" includes an unknown SID: "John"

Is it possible to give rights to one specific user (hard code string)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must say that I find this quite suspicious. Users should not have write permissions to application installation folder. If the application needs to store some data, it should write them to a user profile folder (`C:\Users\username\AppData`) or to a common data folder (`C:\ProgramData`).
See also [Application does not work when installed with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44333839/850848).

---

Anyway, Inno Setup does not support granting permissions to a user. I actually assume, it's because there's no real good use case for that (as explained above).

But you can use Windows [`icacls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls) or [`cacls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cacls) commands from [`[Run]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection) instead.

```
[Run]
Filename: "icacls"; Parameters: """{app}"" /grant John:w"; Flags: runhidden
```

```
[Run]
Filename: "cacls"; Parameters: """{app}"" /e /g John:w"; Flags: runhidden
```