# Create a new users group for inno setup

Tags: permissions, inno-setup, usergroups

I need to create a new usersgroup, because it is not included in the ones already created :

```
authusers   Authenticated Users group
creatorowner    Creator Owner
everyone    Everyone group
guests  Guests group
networkservice  Network service account
service Local service account
system  Local system account
users   Users group
```

The usergroup that I need is IUSR, how can I grant all rights to this group ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup does not have any built-in functionality for creating users groups (nor accounts). Neither it allows settings permissions specifically for a certain group or account.

So for both, you need to invoke respective command-line tools.

- For creating a user group, use [`net localgroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc725622(v=ws.11)).

- For setting permissions, use `cacls` or `icalcs`.
  See [Inno Setup - How to give one specific user rights to a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54147843/850848)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218883/discussion-on-answer-by-martin-prikryl-create-a-new-users-group-for-inno-setup). Please be sure to update the answer to include all relevant information.