# Setup EXE won't start - without any Error Message

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have created a Setup EXE of my Python program with InnoSetup. On most computers it runs without any problems. 
But on some the EXE doesn't do anything at all. No error message or anything like that!

Is there any method for me to check what causes this behaviour?

Also the setup installs to `C:\Program Files` but when i want to start it it just works with admin rights. Is that normal or am i doing somethin wrong?

Comment: Does it generate some log? (`/log` command-line switch). -- Regarding your other question, see [Application does not work when installed with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44333839/850848).

Comment: Never looked into this before. How do i get the log File?

Comment: Again, use `/log` command-line switch, like `setup.exe /log=C:\some\path\setup.log`

Comment: Will try that! Could Take some time, Not my pc, also not my timezone! Thank you very much.

Comment: Have they replied to you?

Comment: No reply yet, maybe after the weekend!