# PermissionError with Inno Compiler Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Receiving the following error after installing my program with Inno Setup:

```
PermissionError[WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\???\\temp\\\???/???'
```

The following line is from my File section which I believe is the issue:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\kirim\Documents\???\???\build\exe.win32-3.7\*"; DestDir: "{app}\exe.win32-3.7"; Permissions: users-modify; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

I've tried without any permissions in that line of code,  tried it with  `Permissions: user-modify;`, and have tried it with `Permissions: everyone-modify` (yes I know this can create potential security issues down the road.

**Also, I have seen the other post that are related to this same permissions issue and there answers are all thing's I tried as mentioned before**

Kind of running out of options. Maybe, if I change the file path to relative this issue could be fixed. I've read a plethora of possible different possibilities so it's confusing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would seem that your program should not assume its install directory is writable. (Temp files should be written to user's temp directory, for example.)

Comment: Is that something you believe I should fix in my program or my installation script?

Comment: As I noted in my first comment, your program should not assume that its installation directory is writable.

Comment: See [Application does not work when installed with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44333839/850848).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions issue stemmed from writing the temp/directory to `C:\Program FIles (X86)\my_project` . A dependency of pywinauto writes some temp files somewhere in there, so I fixed the issue by telling the package to write to our temp directory instead. Was easily to do so because the package had a variable that I could change. Thank you for the help!