# How can I fix my Java application after compiling with Inno Setup to progress beyond the login screen?

Tags: database, javafx, inno-setup

I've been working on a project for 3 months and now i've been trying to compile it to .exe using Inno setup compiling.
The issue is the app works on the first scene, but after typing my login details through MySQL database it doesn't get to the next scene.

My log

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
</log>
```

[image: App image after being compiled]

I tried to reinstall Inno, made sure that the login details are correct but nothing helps.
However if i typed wrong password it shows me that the password is incorrect so it's not database problem

Comment: Does your application have any logging implemented? If so, look at the logs to see what is going wrong. If not, you might want to add logging. Or see if you can at least get it working with `jpackage` (that way you can narrow down the problem--whether it's your code or a problem with Inno Setup configuration).

Comment: According to the Oracle `jpackage` 20 user guide, on Windows, the packaging prerequisites are: ["WiX 3.0 or later is required."](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-786E15C0-2CE7-4BDF-9B2F-AC1C57249134).  I know that Innosetup used to work with older Java packaging tools from Oracle, but I think modern ones require Wix on Windows.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
</log>

This is the log i get

Comment: I don't think that it has anything to do with Wix 3.0 because the installation progress is done correctly, however i'll try.

Comment: I've never used InnoSetup but it should create some bundle with a jar file. See if you can run the jar file directly from the terminal/command prompt so that any stack traces are displayed.

Comment: From Inno Setup point of view, see [Application does not work when installed with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44333839/850848) – without more debugging details from your application, you can hardly get a more specific answer here.